# How to get the current user's role in a custom rally app in production?

Tags: rally

So, I am able to do this fine when testing my custom app in the debug environment provided by rally-app-builder. I use Rally.environment.getContext().getUser() to get the current user, and from the returned object I get the role from the "Role" field. But, for some weird reason, when I use the exact same code in Rally production, Rally.environment.getContext().getUser() returns a different object that has no "Role" field. What is the solution for this problem? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:sad trombone:

This is a defect for sure.  The context object is populated a little differently between the external App SDK bootstrapper and the way it is created when running within the product.

I'm going to file a defect and get this resolved ASAP.  I'll post back here once the fix has been released.  Can you work around it for now?

Comment: Alright thanks! Yeap, I just worked around it a few minutes ago. I had a user store, so I just got the ObjectID from the current user (which is still available in production from the getUser() function) and then looped through the user store and matched for the ObjectID.